# AspectJ + @Configurable

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, aop, aspectj

Trying to use both AspectJ and `@Configurable` with a Spring application.

- If I load Spring with a `@Component` annotation on a class, the AspectJ wrapper works and wraps all targeted methods AND the `@Autowired` annotation causes dependencies to be injected. But the class cannot be instantiated at runtime with the `new` keyword and have dependencies injected.
- If I load a `@Configurable` class without the AspectJ bean, all dependencies are injected correctly on `new` but none of the methods are proxied through AspectJ.

**How can I do both?**

Here's my code. Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example")
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class TestCoreConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityAspect generateSecurityAspect(){
        return new SecurityAspect();
    }


    @Bean
    public SampleSecuredClass createSampleClass(){
        return new SampleSecuredClass();
    }
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class SecurityAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}


    @Around("publicMethod()")
    public boolean test (ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Here!");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        return true;    
    }

}
```

SampleClass:

```
//@Configurable
@Component
public class SampleSecuredClass {

    @Autowired
    public SecurityService securityService;

    public boolean hasSecurityService(){
        return securityService != null;
    }

    public boolean returnFalse(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the unit test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestCoreConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SecurityAspectComponentTest {

    @Autowired
    private SampleSecuredClass sampleSecuredClass;

    @Test
    public void testSecurityRoles(){
        //SampleSecuredClass sampleSecuredClass = new SampleSecuredClass();

        assertTrue("We need to ensure the the @Configurable annotation injected the services correctly", sampleSecuredClass.hasSecurityService());

        assertTrue("We need to ensure the the method has been overwritten", sampleSecuredClass.returnFalse());
    }

}
```

- If I get rid of the beans in the `TestCoreConfig` and create an instance of `SampleSecuredClass` in the test with `new`, and change its annotation to `@Configurable` then the service is injected, but the aspect is not applied.
- If I run as is here (by injecting the `SampleSecuredClass` as a bean), then the aspect works and the service is injected, but then all objects have to be created on framework start. I would like to use the `@Configurable` annotation.
- If I use both the `@Configurable` annotation and the Aspect together then I get a `illegal type in constant pool` error and the context does not start.

---

Other pieces of information.

- I have tried a few different java agents--both spring instrumentation and aspectjwrapper. no change.
- If I include an aop.xml file, then the aspect works but not the @Configurable.

Comment: hmmm set the values to true: no change

Comment: Sorry, haven't read the whole question throughly, but there is an `autowire()` attribute in the `@Configurable` that defaults to `NO`. Have you tried setting it to `BY_TYPE` or `BY_VALUE`?

Comment: sorry, i was trying to edit the comment while you replied. Forget the comment.

Comment: Could it be an option to use a factory method (possibly static) instead of `new` to create a new object? That means `obj = Factory.createObj();` instead of `obj = new SampleSecuredClass ();`.

Comment: Have you tried compile time weaving using aspectj compiler ? you could either add it to your maven config or simply configure the IDE compiler to use ajc

Answer (score 1):

This seems one of those deep dives sessions into the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) waiting to happen :)

First of all I'd enable debug logging for `org.springframework` because this will definitely provide some meaningful insight into what and when Spring does...

That being said I *believe* that your problem lies somewhere in the *mist* of spring's context lifecycles so I'd check out the docs carefully especially around

1. Manually specifying that the bean depends on the configuration aspect `depends-on="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect"`
2. ...or the note  around `@Configurable(preConstruction=true)`

> If you want the dependencies to be injected before the constructor bodies execute

3. ...or `@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME,dependencyCheck=true)`

> Finally you can enable Spring dependency checking for the object references in the newly created and configured object by using the dependencyCheck attribute.

Read the docs carefully, see if and how these hits apply and please let us know the solution you find. It should definitely present itself as a very interesting read.